# Microsoft Graph group members

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm currently dealing with Microsoft Graph API to list members/owners of groups.

I have a few groups, that have both members and owners

I can view both in the Graph API Explorer, .e.g

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/groupID/members
https://graph.microsoft.com/groupID/owners
```

This works fine in the browser and returns a collection of users for the group

I have some code (via Guzzle) that hits the above 2 endpoints. I can get a list of `owners`, but the `members` are always empty.

It returns the following (via `var_dump()`:

```
array(2) {
  '@odata.context' =>
  string(59) 
"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryObjects"
  'value' =>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

My tenant has been given full admin (admin_consent) to be able to deal with this. It just seems odd that I can get owners, but not members.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to get `group member` with this URL `https://graph.microsoft.com/groupID/members` which doestn't seems correct.

Please try below `Microsoft Graph` URL

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/b4699e9c-6b78-Your_Group_ID_39cee27b53/members
```

See The screen shot:

[image]

For details you could refer [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example)